# Right way to use video reward admob?

Tags: admob-rewardedvideoad

My adsense account was disapproved by Google recently. Google did not give me a detail reason,so I do not know what exactly reason cause the problem!

My app have video reward,it shows when user reached 20 turns of view. If user agree to view video reward,they will have 20 more turns to view content. If no,they can not view content. So it is the right scenario for using video reward?

Hope to get advice from you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Was the decline on the initial setup to get the Admob account activated or did you have it running and then it become deactivated? If the latter, it's possible you could have violated their rules on using the ad network (there's a plethora a small reason this could entail). Otherwise, do you have multiple Admob accounts? I've heard rumors that you can be declined for this reason. Sorry if I'm vague - hope this helps (at all).

Comment: Admob account have been running and make revenue. But one day,google show a pop-up: Your adsense account disapproved. Mailed me,they talked about invalid activity but not showed detail.